# Sass check if value is passed to mixin

Tags: variables, sass, scope

Please help me to modify `mixin` and create compatible `function`.

Here is my mixin, it can accept optonal parameter `!important` `true` or `false`, and if `!important` is `true` then output `height` as
`height: 16px !important;` for example:

```
@mixin svg-size($size, !important: true) {
    svg {
        height: $size foo();
        width: $size foo();
    }
}

Call mixin:
@include svg-size(16px, true);

Output:
svg {
    height: 16px !important;
    width: 16px !important;
}
```

I also need a proper name for that kind of function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `conditionally-important` as the function name and use some basic at-rules for flow control returning `!important` if true?

```css
@function conditionally-important ($important) {
  @if $important {
    @return !important; 
  }
  @return null;
}

@mixin svg-size($size, $is-important: true) {
  svg {
      height: $size conditionally-important($is-important);
      width: $size conditionally-important($is-important);
  }
}
```

```css
// Calling as important
@include svg-size(16px, true);
// Output
svg {
    height: 16px !important;
    width: 16px !important;
}

// Calling as not important
@include svg-size(16px, false);
// Output
svg {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Comment: What will happen if I do not indicate either true or false? and can I change ($is-important: true) default value in svg-size mixin to false? Also is there any shorter names for that kind of functions?

Comment: If it's not a boolean, it will follow the rules of the language's truthiness: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/booleans#truthiness-and-falsiness. You can change the `@if` statement to match only true, and an `@else if` that matches only false and then have everything else @error or return null.

Comment: You can change any of the default values and it will still function about the same. I went for clarity when choosing the function name, but you could also pick just `important($is-important)`  as the variable in context explains it decently well. @Urch